# Fit the table to the parent container in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

In my project, I am trying to fit the created table to the parent panel.

**inside panel**

```
var items = [];
```

---

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 6
},
initComponent: function(){
    //creating child items dynamically
    for(var i=0;i<36;i++){
        items.push({
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout:'fit'
        })          
    }
    this.callParent();
}
items: items
```

The child items are being added successfully to the panel, but with `0` dimensions (width and height). How to make the child panels calculate the dimensions to fit themselves in the parent panel?

PS: I can see `36` blocks if I give dimensions manually.

I am also available at [sencha chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23760/sencha)

Comment: Are you pushing the items in the array after this line `items: items`?

Comment: @A1rPun no before that. In `initComponent`. There is no problem in adding child elements. The problem is the child elements are not getting the width and height automatically so that the table fits the container.

Comment: Yeah I see, but if you push items in the item array after the panel is rendered It won't recalculate the layout. Just to make sure ;)

Comment: @A1rPun please check my edit. I hope this will be more clear. I can see `36` blocks if I give dimensions manually. So, I think there is no problem with layout.

Comment: Why not сallParent(arguments) in initComponent()?

Comment: @Vlad sorry, I have not mentioned that. Actually, I am calling `this.callParent();`. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add [`tableAttrs`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table-cfg-tableAttrs) to your layout config to make the parent panel 100% width.

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 6,
    tableAttrs: {
        style: {
            width: '100%'
        }
    }
},
```

And for your items you need to specify a title or html.

```
items.push({
    xtype: 'container',
    html: i.toString(),
    layout:'fit'
})
```

The result with `xtype: 'container', html: i.toString()`:
[image]
The result with `xtype: 'panel', title: i.toString()`:
[image]

Comment: now only height is `0`. I tried giving `height: 100%` but it is messing the layout.

Comment: There is no cross-browser solution for `height: 100%`. You need to hard-code the height for the table or for the individual items in the items array.

Comment: nah, I strongly think this huge framework must have some method to do that. Going through documentation but can't find it. Anyway, thanks for help +1. Hope you have the solution somewhere in corner of your mind :).

Comment: Why are you using panels if you don't have any content in it? You need some sort of content to let the browser calculate the td's inside the table. Thanks for the +1 ;)

Comment: There is no need to even explicitly mention the child containers as `panel` (they are `panel`'s by default as their parent is `panel`). I am just mentioning here to know where could be the problem.

Comment: I did add the html. It just occupying the space of letter vertically. But I need to make even the vertical to occupy the complete space, so that the table can fit the parent panel.

Comment: That is not possible with the table layout. You should consider another layout like a hbox.

Comment: I tried with `hbox` before, all the layout was messing up. please show me sample with it..

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem using `containers` as child items instead of `panels` (which were default). I used `tableAttrs` to stretch the table layout inside the parent panel (As suggested by @A1rPun). and also using `tdAttrs` to show border's to the containers.

```
var items = [];
```

---

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 6

    tableAttrs: {
        style: {
            width: '100%',
            height:'100%'
        }
    },
    tdAttrs: {
       style:{
           border:'1px groove #abc7ec'
       }
    }
},
initComponent: function(){
    for(var i=0;i<36;i++){
        items.push({
             xtype: 'container',
             style:{
                 height:'100%'
             }
        })          
    }
    this.callParent();
},
items: items
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8G5zV/3/)**

Eventhough I solved it, I still think that there could be some built-in method in extjs to stretch the table in a parent panel.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this:

```
...
items: [],

initComponent: function() {
    for(var i=0; i<36; i++) {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout:'fit',
            items: []
        });          
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

**Update:**

```
items: [],

initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    for(var i=0; i<36; i++) {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout:'fit',
            html: 'Content'
        });
    }
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8G5zV/

Comment: This is what I thought the first time I saw this question but Mr_Green already explained that it is not the case.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'insert' ` I am getting this error.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes. Need to calling callParent() before adding items. See http://jsfiddle.net/8G5zV/

Comment: @Mr_Green Wow, no. It's a style: {width: '100 %'} of A1rPun :)

Comment: It is funny because your solution is the same as mine.. just adding the panels in a different way.

Comment: @A1rPun Yes, I was ctrl + c/v and not noticed your style )

Comment: No problemo ;) your jsfiddle makes this case easier to solve.

Comment: your solution is same as A1rpun's it is not occupying complete space vertically, which is what I want. see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8G5zV/1/